# Android: Dont find icon with the 3 points

Tags: android

I can't find this icon for my actionbar:
[image: Picture of the searched icon]

Do you know where i can get it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding images in the real world, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at C:\Program Files\android\sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light.png

or derivates of it with the name ic_menu_moreoverflow

Comment: Thank you this is what i searched for :D

Comment: Could you mark this question as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

In lower versions of android, you will not get this 3 points icon on actionbar. You have to use menu button for menu items. whereas in latest versions menu button is removed so this icon appears on actionbar and acts as menu button